# Are all the mods on Unix&Linux such dictators?

Tags: discussion

I've had a question shut down because someone doesn't like people to have a discussion.  Anyone else encounter such a poor attitude here ?  Is this indicative of the atmosphere one might expect here ?

Comment: Not sure about *poor attitude*, more a misunderstanding of the policies on your behalf. This is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. Have you considered finding a suitable subreddit for instance?

Comment: What Stack Exchange userid did you use to ask this question? I see no questions associated with your current ID. However, this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum, so attempts to have a discussion will get shut down.

Comment: "Dictator" is a term used for politicians. It doesn't include site admins or house owners etc.

Answer (score 14):

Thank you for bringing up your issue on the Meta site.

I have located the *answer* that you wrote.  It was posted containing a question about one of the other answers to the same question (unsure which one), and since it wasn't attempting to answer the question at hand, it was flagged by a user as "not an answer" within an hour.  After another hour with some back and forth in the answer's comments, a moderator stepped in and removed the answer.

Reviewing the answer and the timeline of actions, I believe the user who flagged the message as "not an answer" did the right thing and that the moderator who finally acted on the flag did the right thing.

In cases like these, when you have a similar issue as someone who asked a question, but you can't get any (or a particular) answer to work for you, you have two choices:

1. You may comment on the specific answer you don't understand or can't get to work, asking the author to explain their reasoning further or to consider whatever context may make your attempts fail.  This may be an alternative if you have the "reputation" to leave comments. It may be a dead-end approach if the question and/or answers are many years old.
   Note that the author has no obligation to respond and that both of you should avoid creating a long comment thread that does not result in *an improvement to the answer*. When the discussion is over, the comments should ideally be deleted by yourselves or by flagging for moderator attention. See also the *main* Meta post [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)
2. You may ask a new question: "I'm having *this issue*, which is similar to the issue in *this other question*.  I tried *this answer to the other question*, but I can't get it to work properly.  *This* is my context, *this* is exactly what I'm trying to do, *this* is exactly what I expect to happen, and *this* is exactly what actually happens when I try the approach that I found or came up with."

Discussions are *good*, but StackExchange sites, including U&L, are not forums for discussion.  There are other sites for that. This is not about attitude but about trying to focus on the main task of the site, which is to be an encyclopedia of questions with informed answers.  This is brought up in this post to the *main* Meta site: [Are Stack Exchange sites forums?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums)

Finally, about being "dictators": A "dictator" is someone "holding complete autocratic control: a person with unlimited governmental power", or "one ruling in an absolute and often oppressive way" (def. from Merriam Webster).  These definitions are true in a *technical* sense in that our *votes* are overriding and that we have more buttons to press on the website (allowing us to do things non-moderators can not do). It is *not true* in the sense that we can do what we want without caring about what others think.  In particular, we listen to input from users, we ask for help when assessing technically tricky cases, and we attempt to own and fix our own mistakes (something I'm getting better at and something terdon, who is the moderator who deleted your answer, is particularly good at, IMHO).

As moderators, we are bound by the [Moderator Agreement](https://unix.stackexchange.com/legal/moderator-agreement), which includes the [Code of Conduct](https://unix.stackexchange.com/conduct), the [Terms of Service](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public), and the [Privacy Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/privacy-policy).

If you believe a moderator made the wrong decision, bring it up here on Meta for review.  If it's a *serious* case of obviously breaking the Moderator Agreement, you may also contact the support team with a "Trust and Safety" or "Other" issue (see link at the bottom of every page).

Comment: And community moderators such as @terdon and yourself are [democratically elected](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/election).